# Getting value from component class in main class.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have shown some fields in my component page and i am using that component in my main page..I want to get the list value that i have used in my component class to my main controller class..I tried to extend my component class and tried to access the list but i am getting a null list..

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="objectComController">
 <apex:repeat value="{!objectList}" var="wra" id="theRepeat">
  <apex:inputField value="{!wra.nameField}"></apex:inputField>
 </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

**Component Class**

```
public with sharing abstract class objectComController{
public List<object__c> objectList{get;set;}

public objectComController()
{
    objectList=new List<object__c>();
}

}
```

I am getting the values in **objectList** in this component controller.

**Main Class** where i have used this controller

```
public with sharing class mainClass extends objectComController{

   public void Save()
   {
       System.debug('============'+objectList);

   }
}
```

When i am trying to debug the values of the list in my maincontroller the values are coming null.I just need to get my list values from my component class in my main class.

Its very urgent for me.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This has been documented in the below blog link

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

Also its been answered at stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103363/how-to-get-in-a-visualforce-page-controller-a-value-from-a-custom-component-cont